# show that $[a]^4=[3]$ is not possible

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

when doing a proof by contradiction I have reached a statement that states
$[a]^4=[3]$ for modulo 7. I know that since its modular arithmetic $a=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ and obviously $[0]^4=[0]$ and $[7]^4=[0]$ Is it value to check all the other possible values of $a$ to derive a contradiction that $[a]^4=[3]$ will never occur in modulo 7?

Comment: You should probably edit your title. And yes, it is valid to simply check $[a]^4 \ne [3]$ for all $a=0,\ldots,6$. (You don't need to check $7$ since $[0]=[7]$.)

Comment: In other words you can replace the base of a power $a^b$ modulo $n$ by $a\mod n$, which can only lead to a problem if $n|a$ and $b=0$ , in which case we would get $0^0$. If we accept the definition $0^0=1$, then we do not need this slight restriction.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for $[a]^2$ you have:$$0,1,2,4$$ then for for $[a]^4$ you have:$$0,1,2,4$$

Comment: Also, since $[a]^4=([a]^2)^2$, the first line is already enough to prove that $[a]^4\neq 3$.

Comment: $[4]^2=\left[4^2\right]=[16]=2.$

Comment: ops you are right!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with even powers, it's often easier to start with both positive and negative numbers modulo the base, keeping the magnitude of the numbers low.

So here, the possibilities are $a \equiv 0,\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3 \pmod 7$

Taking the fourth powers, $a^4 \equiv 0, 1, 2^4 = 16 \equiv 2, 3^4 = 81 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$.

Doing it this way allows us to simplify the work.